SwiftUI - understanding optional views modifiers
Please consider the following view which uses a failable initializer:
struct MyOptionalView: View {
    
    private let someParameter: String
    
    init?(someParameter: String?) {
        guard let someParameter else {
            return nil
        }
        self.someParameter = someParameter
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(someParameter)
        }
    }
}

I can use it as
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MyOptionalView(someParameter: nil)
        }
    }
}

If I now try to add a modifier, e.g. .background(Color.green), XCode will automatically add a ? before the dot:
MyOptionalView(someParameter: nil)
        ?.background(Color.green)

but this code will not compile - XCode now shows an error

Expected ':' after '? ...' in ternary expression

I can remove the question mark and now the code will be built fine.
My question is - what does exactly happen while using optional views ? Why can I add the modifiers without unwrapping ? Are there any risks associated with these ?
I could barely find any information on the handling of the optional views in SwiftUI.

You are able to use values of optional types without unwrapping because Optional<T> conforms to View when T conforms to View! The effect is similar to when you use an if in a ViewBuilder.
MyOptionalView(someParameter: nil)
// is similar to
if let view = MyOptionalView(someParameter: nil) {
    view
}

// and

MyOptionalView(someParameter: nil)
    .background(.green)
// is similar to
Group {
    if let view = MyOptionalView(someParameter: nil) {
        view
    }
}
.background(.green)

?.background(Color.green) doesn't compile simply because that's not the correct syntax. If you want to put the view modifier on another line, the ? should be on the first line, and . on the second line.
MyOptionalView(someParameter: nil)?
    .background(.green)


I think my question was a bit misunderstood. This syntax comes from XCode (so seems like a bug). What I am wondering is - why can I remove that question mark completely and the code still works ? How is it possible to use modifiers on optionals without unwrapping ?

@BenTheProgrammer I believe my first sentence answers that. Optionals are Views themselves, so you can use view modifiers on them.

@BenTheProgrammer you can go to the documentation page for Optional, scroll down to the very bottom to see what protocols it conforms to, and you’d see View in that list.

now I see, thank you

This is because the view returned by the initializer can be optional. SwiftUI doesn't know how to act on "optional" views, there must either be a view or not.
Instead of doing the guard in the view's initializer, try doing the check in the body instead, like this:
struct MyOptionalView: View {
    private let someParameter: String?
    
    init(someParameter: String?) {
        self.someParameter = someParameter
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        if let someParameter {
            VStack {
                Text(someParameter)
            }
        }
    }
}

MyOptionalView(someParameter: nil)
    .background(Color.green)

You can see that with this small edit, the view is now not optional anymore, but the parameter still is
